# SQL conditional field, first match JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets imagine I have two tables:

```
user
--userid
--fname
--lname

widget
--id
--userid
--value
```

`user.userid = widget.userid`

I want to see the full list of users with the `Widget.value` if they have one, **AND(!)** the first match if there are more than 1 widget. No widget = null field

```
id    fname   lname  value
 1     John     Doe    X8
```

I can not do simple joins, cos if there is no 'widget.value' for some 'user' user won't be displayed

`CROSS APPLY` doesn't work as well

I need

- 1 widget = value
- > 2 widgets = first one
- 0 widgets = null field

Comment: You'll need to define "first match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outer apply` should do what you want:

```
select u.*, w.value
from user u outer apply
     (select top 1 w.*
      from widgets w
      where w.userid = u.userid
      order by id  -- or however you define the first one
     ) w;
```

Answer (score 1):

using [top with ties](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option):

```
select top 1 with ties
  u.*, w.id, w.value
from dbo.user u
  left join dbo.widget w 
    on u.userid = w.userid
order by row_number() over (partition by u.userid order by w.id);
```

---

using [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
    select u.*, w.id, w.value
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by u.userid order by w.id)
    from dbo.user u
      left join dbo.widget w 
        on u.userid = w.userid
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  u.userid, u.fname, u.lname, w.value
FROM user as u
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT w1.*
   FROM widget as w1
   INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT userid, MAX(id) AS LatestId
      FROM widget
      GROUP BY userid
   ) AS w2 ON w1.userid = w2.userid and w1.id = w2.latestid
) AS w ON u.userid = w.userid;
```

- The inner join with subquery with max and group by, will give you the latest row for each userid if any. So for those with more than 1 row you will get the latest one.
- There is no date, so I assumed the max id is the latest one, which might not always the case.
- `LEFT JOIN` will include those rows with un matched rows form the widget table, so if there is a user with no widget you will get a value `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.userid, w.value
FROM user u
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 w.value
    FROM widget w
    WHERE w.userid = u.userid
    ORDER BY w.id --order by whatever makes a widget the first one
) w
```